# success and failure callbacks in realm xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am looking for callbacks related to add and read data in `realm` with `xamarin`.

Here i am fetching data from server and adding into realm , but i want an event where in i can notify UI that `company` data has been added to realm successfully and if any error comes i can show that too.

```
 var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Company company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(content);
                    Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance();
                    await  realm.WriteAsync(tempRealm => {

                        tempRealm.Add(company);

                    });
```

in android native we have following function to execute any transaction in background and can notify for success and failure.

```
final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(App.getRealmConfig());
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {

        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userResponseInfo.getCallInfoList());


    }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {

    }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {


    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm Xamarin uses the standard .NET mechanism of propagating errors from tasks, which is why you don't need a success and error callbacks. If an error occurred, an exception will be thrown that can be handled in a regular try-catch block:

```
try
{
    var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    await realm.WriteAsync(temp => temp.Add(company));
    // if control reaches this line the transaction executed successfully.
    notifier.NotifySuccess();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // The transaction failed - handle the exception
    notifier.NotifyError(ex.Message);
}
```